# transliterate a portion of the input

Tags: sed

Could I get some pointers for a sed script to transliterate like y/abc/123/
but only on some of input. The processing would follow these rules:

1. enable transliterate once ¡ char seen
2. disable once µ char seen (may be on diff line to ¡)
3. never transliterate between &; or <> chars

Comment: Sounds like you need a full-blown parser, not sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in `sed`, but it's going to be *extremely* painful.  Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. would be better choices.

If you *must* do it in `sed`, the basic approach is to preserve parts of the line you don't want to change in the hold buffer, working your way through the line and appending completed portions to the hold buffer until the main buffer is empty, then pull the hold buffer back into the main buffer.  Also, you want to have two separate loops, one for transliterating mode (entered on `¡`) and the other for passthrough mode (the initial mode, and entered on `µ`).